# The content database on the server is temporarily unavailable (sharepoint online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-addin, content-database

Currently I am working on an application based on sharepoint add-in webpart(sharepoint hosted) in sharepoint online which was getting deployed successfully till yesterday, but today when I deployed it, it gave the following error

```
    ErrorDetail: The content database on the server is temporarily 
    unavailable.
    ErrorType: Transient
    ErrorTypeName: Intermittent
    ExceptionMessage: The request could not be completed because of a 
    failure of writng to DNS.
    Source: AppWeb
    SourceName: App Web Deployment
    Error occurred in deployment step 'Install SharePoint Add-in': Failed to 
    install SharePoint Add-in. Please see the output window for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a new issue in the SharePoint Online, sometimes happened and automatically solved after a few minutes of waiting!

**So I suggest doing the following:**

1. Create a simple Add-In and try to publish it to make sure that the issue is not related to your Add-In, if you face the same issue, so it's not related to your main Add-In.
2. Also, try to publish your `Add-In` to another tenant, if you have!

If the problem is not solved until now, so you should raise a Microsoft ticket to get it solved!

Comment: hello mohamad I am getting this issue in a new app also and its been 6 hours and am still getting this error

Comment: Hello, @RajeevKumar , That means the issue is not related to your main Add-In, you should open [SR with Microsoft](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/) to solve it.